# When I am using data in return the showing the data but when I am refreshing the page it through an error)

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, user-interface, frontend

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
fetch('api/dashboard/userDetails')
.then((data)=>setUser(data.data?.data)
},[])

return(
<div>{user[0].name}</div>
<div>{user[0].age}</div>
<div>{user[0].years}</div>
)
```

I fetch data from an api. Data comes in a form of an array

```
user = [{ name: abc, age: 45, years: 7 }];
```

When I am using data in return the showing the data but when I am refreshing the page it through an error :

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the code isinde your `jsx` runs before `useEffect`. 
you can initialize the state with an empty string :

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("");
```

then before displaying you check :

```
return (
  <>
    {user === "" ? (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    ) : (
      <>
        <div>{user[0].name}</div>
        <div>{user[0].age}</div>
        <div>{user[0].years}</div>
      </>
    )}
  </>
);
```